# Tutorial for Unit Testing with VS 2010

Tags: .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2010, testing

I am new in unit testing and need some book or tutorial. I have looked alot in google, but can't find anything. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008859/getting-started-with-unit-testing-in-vs2010) question, but there is no answer, that's why I am asking it too.
Is there anything from which I can start?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The art of Unit testing](http://artofunittesting.com/)

by [Roy Osherove](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/)

I didn't understand the concept of unit testing until I read this great book!

It guides you step by step from simple tests to tests that are maintainable, readable and trustworthy. It covers advanced subjects like mocks, stubs and frameworks such as TypeMock and Rhine.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for link, I will download that book.

Comment: Kind of sucks that the author of that book dislikes Stack Exchange and calls for our failure: http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2010/09/24/why-stackexchange-will-eventually-fail-control-freak-ism.aspx

Answer (score 6):

If you are new to unit testing, in addition to learning the tools, I would recommend learning a bit about how to write testable code. E.g. using dependency injection and abstraction as a test seam.

This video goes over the basics: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEhu57pih5w. It is more at the conceptual level than being a tutorial, but nevertheless is well worth watching.

Comment: can you expand on what you mean by a "test seam"?

Comment: Sure, that was, perhaps, a completely non-descriptive statement. I think of seams as being related to depending on abstractions rather than concretions. If your class depends on an abstraction, it is easy to substitute collaborator classes with mocks. Abstractions therefore act as the seams between the testable units of your program. Typically, you test at these seams by verifying state and/or behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The NUnit website has a good easy tutorial in the documentation for each release. More of a quick start guide than an in-depth book on testing.

Heres a link: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=getStarted&r=2.5.7