# Looking for a tutorial to start with Unit Test and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

What are the tutorial best suit for us to get start with Unit Test in Visual Studio 2010?
Hope to hear from you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365943/how-to-start-unit-testing-or-tdd

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3522926/tutorial-for-unit-testing-with-vs-2010/3522981#3522981

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the following book:
http://artofunittesting.com/